# To store value of textbox in session

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

Here, If I write name of textbox is id from an array, then how it would be use in session.?

**Updated:**
My code is:

```
foreach($abc as $row)
{
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="txt" id=txt_"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onblur="doAjax(this)"/>
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('blur','.txt',function(){

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "view_orders_checked_array.php",
            data: {task: 'alltxt'},
            async: false
        });
 });
```

In view_orders_checked_array.php:

```
if($task == "alltxt")
{
    $_SESSION["textareaID"] = [];
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        $al[] = array_push($_SESSION["textareaIDs"], $row["id"]);
    }
    print_r($al);
}
```

So, how it would possible to store textbox value in session array.?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing it. Are you a beginner or intermediate programmer?

Comment: I am beginner...!! @Ali Zia

Comment: So read about sessions :) A lot of tutorials and manual is there. Simple and short. And if you new in php, remember: Dont ask anywhere if you se error "Headers already sent", when you start using sessions. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Start the session at the top of every page that you want to access the session:

```
<?php session_start();
```

Then to add data to the session array:

```
<?php $_SESSION["foo"] = $bar; ?>
```

---

So if your textarea ID is `$row["id"]`, you can do:

```
<?php $_SESSION["textareaID"] = $row["id"]; ?>
```

then call it whenever you want by doing:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["textareaID"]; ?>
```

Of course, you can name the session array variable anything you want.

---

Or in a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
$_SESSION["textareaIDs"] = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    array_push($_SESSION["textareaIDs"], $row["id"]);
} ?>
```

Comment: My textbox name is from an array that is $row.
So, is this like,
<?php $_SESSION["row"] = $bar; ?>

is this right or wrong?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, There is a foreach loop. If you use `<?php $_SESSION["textareaID"] = $row["id"]; ?>`, The value of `$_SESSION["textareaID"]` will be overlapped by the recent one. At the end, `$_SESSION["textareaID"]` will only have just the last value of `$row['id']`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay I'm starting to understand what you're trying to do - the edit will add the ID to an array in the session.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan. That is exactly what I would have done. This seems to be the correct answer. :)